# Efficient Pandas stock calculation

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a dataset of birth and death dates, like this:

```
d1 = {'Birth_date': [1800,1810,1802,1804], 'Death_date': [1805, 1880,1854,1832]}
pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

   Birth_date  Death_date
0        1800        1805
1        1810        1880
2        1802        1854
3        1804        1832
```

I want to compute:

- The stock of living individuals for a given year at a given age (*for instance the number of individuals of age 18 living in 1825*)
- The number of deaths for a given year at a given age (*for instance the number of 18 yo people who died in 1825*)

In theory, the output would look like this:

```
   Date Number ind. aged 1 Number ind. aged 2 Number ind. aged k
0  1800                 .                 .                 .
1  1801                 .                 .                 .
2  1802                 .                 .                 .
3  1803                 .                 .                 .
```

and

```
   Date Number death aged 1 Number death aged 2 Number death aged k
0  1800                 .                 .                 .
1  1801                 .                 .                 .
2  1802                 .                 .                 .
3  1803                 .                 .                 .
```

I don't see any easy way to compute it. Has-someone faced a similar question ?

Answer (score 0):

**Q1: The stock of living individuals for a given year at a given age and year:**

Given dataframe `d1` as in above question:

```
d2 = \
pd.concat(\
    d1.apply(\
        lambda x: pd.DataFrame(\
        {'id': x.name,\
         'year': range(x['Birth_date'], x['Death_date']+1),\
         'age': range(x['Birth_date'], x['Death_date']+1)-x['Birth_date']}),\
     axis = 1).to_list())
```

`d2` looks like:

```
    id  year  age
0    0  1800    0
1    0  1801    1
2    0  1802    2
3    0  1803    3
4    0  1804    4
..  ..   ...  ...
24   3  1828   24
25   3  1829   25
26   3  1830   26
27   3  1831   27
28   3  1832   28

[159 rows x 3 columns]
```

`id` represents individual person inferred from index of `d1`.
Next just pivot `d2` counting living people at given age and year:

```
nlvng = pd.pivot_table(d2, columns = 'age', index = 'year', values = 'id', aggfunc = 'count', fill_value=0)
```

result set:

```
age   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   ...  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70
year                                      ...                                    
1800   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1801   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1802   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1803   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1804   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ...  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
1876   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
1877   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
1878   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
1879   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
1880   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1

[81 rows x 71 columns]
```

**Q2: The number of deaths for a given year at a given age:**

Here using previously calculated `d2` merge it to `d1` by `d1.index` and `Death_date`:

```
d3 = d2.merge(d1, left_on = ['id','year'], right_on = [d1.index,'Death_date'], how = 'outer')

ndeaths = pd.pivot_table(d3, columns = 'age', index = 'year', values = 'Death_date', aggfunc = 'count', fill_value=0)
```

output:

```
age   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   ...  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70
year                                      ...                                    
1800   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1801   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1802   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1803   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1804   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ...  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
1876   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1877   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1878   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1879   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1880   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1

[81 rows x 71 columns]
```

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**: Sorry, totally wrong answer in the first place.

Now I think this might come near to that what was requested. It might not be the most efficient solution - maybe someone else finds something better?

The solution first creates an artificial df with all years possible and a column for each individual. Then it calculates the age of each person in each year - and finally counts the possible values per year and person age.

```
import pandas as pd


def ind_age(x, min_val, max_val):
    if min_val <= x < max_val:
        return x - min_val + 1  # a person has no age 0
    else:
        return 0

# init df
d1 = {'Birth_date': [1800, 1810, 1802, 1804], 'Death_date': [1805, 1880, 1854, 1832]}
d1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

# min and max years to init df
min_year = d1[['Birth_date', 'Death_date']].min().min()
max_year = d1[['Birth_date', 'Death_date']].max().max()

# get all years possible as a column
df_years = pd.DataFrame(range(min_year, max_year + 1))
df_years.columns = ['years']

# transpose to prepare left join
# the left join will make it possible to insert custom values
# for each year and person
d1 = d1.transpose()

for colname in d1.columns:
    # calculates the age of a person in each year
    df_years = pd.merge(left=df_years, right=pd.DataFrame(d1[colname]), how='left', left_on='years', right_on=colname)

for col in df_years.columns[1:]:
    col_min = df_years[col].min()
    col_max = df_years[col].max()
    df_years[col] = df_years['years'].apply(lambda x: ind_age(x, col_min, col_max))

df_years.set_index('years', inplace=True)

result = df_years.apply(pd.Series.value_counts, axis=1).fillna(0)
```

The result looks like:

```
       0.0   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0   ...  65.0  66.0  67.0  68.0  69.0  70.0
years                                      ...                                    
1800    3.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1801    3.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1802    2.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1803    2.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1804    1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
     ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...  ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
1876    3.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1877    3.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0
1878    3.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
1879    3.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0
1880    4.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
[81 rows x 71 columns]
```

For the deaths you may modifiy the ind_age() method to only return a value on the death day ( x == max_val ) and return the corresponding death age. Depends on how you like to calculate the age ( starting at 0 or 1 ).

Comment: Thanks but no. This only provides the number of births and deaths for a given date. It doesn't provide the number of living individuals of a given age at a given date.